# DialogFlow V2 gRPC (c#) (updating entities, etc.)

Tags: c#, dialogflow-es, grpc

I have to refactor DialogFlow (previously API.AI) from V1 API to new V2 gRPC. So I prepared everything and started refactoring.
But immediately I had some issues. See the example below, when trying to update entities for some entityType.

updateEntity.**Synonyms** is **READ-ONLY** property.

W00t ??? Any idea why is that? Or is there another (proper?) way to do this?

```
var client = DialogFlowHelper.DialogFlowCreateChannelClientEntityTypes();

List<EntityEntry> input = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<EntityEntry>>(jsonData);

List<EntityType.Types.Entity> updateEntities = new List<EntityType.Types.Entity>();

foreach (var e in input)
{
    var updateEntity = new EntityType.Types.Entity();
    updateEntity.Value = e.value;

    // HERE IS THE PROBLEM !!!!
    // HERE IS THE PROBLEM !!!!
    // HERE IS THE PROBLEM !!!!
    //updateEntity.Synonyms = 

    updateEntities.Add(updateEntity);
}

var res = await client.BatchUpdateEntitiesAsync(
    new EntityTypeName("no_problem", "no_problem"),
    updateEntities
    );
```

Definiton for **Synonyms** goes like this:

```
//
// Summary:
//     Required. A collection of synonyms. For `KIND_LIST` entity types this must contain
//     exactly one synonym equal to `value`.
[DebuggerNonUserCode]
public RepeatedField<string> Synonyms { get; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the issue.

Synonyms collection (RepeatedField) is ALREADY existing as an empty collection. So you can just add items to it!